# eBay API GetSellerList call in C# returns error 14005 'Web Service framework internal error. execute exception.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, ebay-api

I have code to get all the listings of my users.  This code has always worked and still is working, but for one particular store it throws an error after getting to a specific number of listings.  It won't get past 18,398 listings when this user has 40k+ number of listings.  I've pulled more listings than that with the same code without any problems.

```
var oContext = oContextMain(conSql);
var call = new GetSellerListCall(oContext);
call.DetailLevelList.Add(DetailLevelCodeType.ReturnAll);
call.Pagination = new PaginationType() { EntriesPerPage = 200 };
call.EndTimeFrom = DateTime.UtcNow;
call.EndTimeTo = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someSetting"]));

call.IncludeWatchCount = true;

do
{
    call.Pagination.PageNumber++;

    ItemTypeCollection items = call.GetSellerList();
```

The line the error message comes from  the

> call.GetSellerList()

Here is the message from eBay logging:

```
[12/12/2017 3:07:28 PM, Informational]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Header>
    <RequesterCredentials xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
      <eBayAuthToken>******</eBayAuthToken>
    </RequesterCredentials>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetSellerListRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
      <DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>
      <MessageID>9c06db99-56ab-4ba4-ad4a-e38c34cee41e</MessageID>
      <Version>981</Version>
      <EndTimeFrom>2017-12-12T19:54:29.8672456Z</EndTimeFrom>
      <EndTimeTo>2018-04-11T19:54:29.8672456Z</EndTimeTo>
      <Pagination>
        <EntriesPerPage>200</EntriesPerPage>
        <PageNumber>93</PageNumber>
      </Pagination>
      <IncludeWatchCount>true</IncludeWatchCount>
    </GetSellerListRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:Fault>
      <faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">ns1:Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Web Service framework internal error.</faultstring>
      <faultactor>http://www.ebay.com/ws/websvc/eBayAPI</faultactor>
      <detail>
        <FaultDetail>
          <ErrorCode>14005</ErrorCode>
          <Severity>Error</Severity>
          <DetailedMessage>Web Service framework internal error. execute exception.</DetailedMessage>
        </FaultDetail>
      </detail>
    </soapenv:Fault>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

[12/12/2017 3:07:29 PM, Error]
Web Service framework internal error. execute exception.
```

Any advise you can give me would be of great help.  I'm stuck and don't know where to go.

Comment: Here is an example with a detailed description. https://ebaydts.com/eBayKBDetails?KBid=858. If the current link doesn't help generate the error fix, another path is ebay developer forum; https://forums.developer.ebay.com/topics/getsellerlist.html

Comment: any chance this could be a DOS?  How many times is the loop getting called?  Do you have any thread sleep in between?

Comment: Very unlikely it's a DOS.  Like I said same exact code works for stores 3 times the size of the one that is giving me the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The code block to get all listings from Seller using - **GetSellerList** is correct.

There is a limit in response items (max of 200) for this API and this may exceeds within the date range you have configured.

This particular seller may have more (> 200) listed items within that specified date range.

To fix this, try with more filters or reduce the date range value to reduce the items count in response

Comment: Yes, I limit it to 200 entries per page.  Then I do a step through each page with the do loop.  Same code has pulled in a store that had 80k worth of listings without any problems.  But this particular customer it always crashes at the same spot which is at 18,398 records.

Comment: It seems to be an error in the ebay system. Maybe there is at least one defect item which caused this. Did you try to skip that page? You can also load that "defect" page with 200 calls and a pagesize of 1 to get the defect item

Comment: @SirRufo I'm going to try to see about skipping that page and see what happens. thanks.